# Using Realm to store nearby locations from Foursquare

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have been experimenting using Realm for iOS. My test project takes in data from Foursquare and stores some of the JSON data into Realm (i.e Name, Coordinates, address, etc). I then filter the locations in the Realm database to display what is close the user. This is all just to avoid calling Foursquare's API except for when the iOS device moves a greater distance away, or the user is offline.

My understanding is that each time data is written to the Realm database, the number of entries in Realm grows and grows and these entries may no longer be useful or relevant to the user after a while. I don't want to take up storage space that isn't needed.

**My question is:** What is the best way with Realm to purge the irrelevant entries to save space when the user's location changes? My thought was to add a NSDate() object to each entry and then remove ones past a certain date. Is there a better way or a best practice with Realm?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your case doesn't seem to be related to any databases but most likely to your app architecture itself and your caching policy. There's no any default cache expiration mechanism in Realm, but the suggested question in comments could be useful for `NSDate()` approach: [Realm Cleaning Up Old Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641221/realm-cleaning-up-old-objects)