# Clean up old Realm objects?

Tags: java, android, realm

Is there a simple way to delete old data from a Realm database? Like if some object has one day stored **automatically** delete it?

The alternative could be to add a field with the date and extract and compare it to decide if delete, but **the question is if Realm has a method itself to achieve this**.

### I'm not looking for a query

The question is whether there is any other way to **automatically** remove old objects from Realm, such as a condition when we store data, a parameter, a **configuration** or a Realm method, **and not just compare each time**. ***It is obvious that with a query we can eliminate any object
that we want.***

I already saw some similar questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641221/realm-cleaning-up-old-objects)) about this, **but none for Android**
**(or Java)**, in the [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest) the only similar approach I found is
about [migrations.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations)

The specification of the linked question (**not the answer**), is just to clarify that this is not a Swift-based question and not mark it as duplicate at first glance.

Comment: `add a field with the date and extract and compare it to decide if delete` yeah you can do `realm.where(MyClass.class).lowerThan("date", someDate).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there is not such functionality in Realm itself.

Your alternative is good but I do not recommend to use background service for deleting data, so check/delete data when you query.

Answer (score 9):

Add a field with the date and query the ones you want to delete based on that

Then you can do

```
 realm.where(MyClass.class)
    .lowerThan("date", someDate)
    .findAll()
    .deleteAllFromRealm()
```

**EDIT:**

> The question is whether there is any other way to automatically remove old objects from Realm, such as a condition when we store data, a parameter, a configuration or a Realm method, and not just compare each time.

No

> **It is obvious that with a query we can eliminate any object that we want.**

The linked Swift-based answer does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yupp you can delete old realm data just like this,

```
realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

In above lines, second line that is

```
Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
```

perform deleting  old realm data. Or you can delete data of specific class as,

```
realm.where(YourClass.class)
    .lowerThan("date", currentDate)
    .findAll()
    .deleteAllFromRealm()
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the alarm manager to every day (24 hr interval)
On alarm manager callback just use the bellow code to delete older data

```
realm.where(BeanClass.class)
    .lowerThan("date", currentDate)
    .findAll()
    .deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Comment: At least this answer is more creative because of the alarm manager

Comment: You could even put it in a BaseActivity.onStart() with executeTransactionAsync if there are any items that should be deleted. I didn't realize this question was also about "how to execute a periodic task on Android".